# Line Integral (Absolute value Function)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm suppose to calculate the line integral of following:

$\int_C (x^2+y^2)dx + (x^2-y^2)dy$,

where C : y = 1- |1-x|, $0 \leq x \leq 2$

I tried to solve this problem by assuming,

x = t  $=>$ dx =dt

then,
y = 1 - |1 - t| $=>$ dy = -sign|1 - t| dt = $ \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & t > 1 \\
      0 & t = 1 \\
      - 1 & t <1 \\
\end{array} 
\right.$

on plugging these value in my original integral, I would get,

$\int_0^2 [t^2 + (1-|1-t|^2 )]dt - [t^2-(1-|1-t|^2)sign|1-t|]dt$

Now, how would I integrate such a function? Or did I do something wrong already?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Consider $0\le x\le 1$ then $y=x$ and $1\lt x\le 2$ then $y=2-x$.

A path $C$ is not a loop. You just evaluate the integral with two intervals.

It will be helpful that drawing the graph of the path(domain).

Comment: That makes so much of sense and much simpler way.. thanks...

Comment: :D You're welcome.